# Applying ppolicy.ldif in OpenLdap

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, rhel7, slapd

I just added the ppolicy.ldif schema to ldap by running the following:

```
ldapadd -T EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
```

I then try to ldapadd my change.ldif file seen below

```
#changes.ldif file
dn: cn=Standard,ou:Policies,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
cn: Standard
pwdAttribute: userPassword
```

Using the command:

```
ldapadd -x -w ldappass -D cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com -f changes.ldif
```

I get the following error:

```
ldap_add: invalid syntax (21)
      additional info: pwdAttribute: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Can somebody tell me what could be causing this?  I am not sure what syntax is incorrect.

I am doing this specifically using slapd.d not slap.conf.  Also working using RHEL7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've loaded the `ppolicy` schema but I suspect you haven't loaded the `ppolicy` module or enabled the overlay on the database.

Without doing that you can only add the `pwdAttribute` using the OID for the `userPassword` attribute, which is `2.5.4.35`.